# Nodemailer problem: { "code": "EAUTH", "command": "API" }

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I try with this code but I got this error {
"code": "EAUTH",
"command": "API"
}

USER_EMAIL= my email
USER_PSW= App Passwords generated by gmail

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",

  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.USER_PSW,
  },
});
```

Comment: It means there's an authentication error.

Comment: but everything is ok user and pass

Comment: Not according to Google.